# Slicing a box of certain width along arbitrary line through 3d array

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, multidimensional-array, slice

I have a big (600,600,600) numpy array filled with my data. Now I would like to extract regions from this with a given width around an arbitrary line through the box.

For the line I have the x, y and z coordinates of every point in separate numpy arrays. So let's say the line has 35 points in the data box, then the x, y and z arrays each have lengths of 35 as well. I can extract the points along the line itself by using indexing like this

```
extraction = data[z,y,x]
```

Now ideally I'd like to extract a box around it by doing something like the following

```
extraction = data[z-3:z+3,y-3:y+3,z-3:z+3]
```

but because x, y and z are arrays, this is not possible. The only way I could think of of doing this is through a for-loop for each point, so

```
extraction = np.array([])
for i in range(len(x)):
    extraction = np.append(extraction,data[z[i]-3:z[i]+3,y[i]-3:y[i]+3,z[i]-3:z[i]+3])
```

and then reshaping the extraction array afterwards. However, this is very slow and there will be some overlap between each of the slices in this for-loop I'd like to prevent.

Is there a simple way to do this directly without a for-loop?

EDIT:
Let me rephrase the question through another idea I came up with that is also slow. I have a line running through the datacube. I have a lists of x, y and z coordinates (the coordinates being the indices in the datacube array) with all the points that define the line.
As an example these lists look like this:

```
 x_line: [345 345 345 345 342 342 342 342 342 342 342 342 342 342 342 342]
 y_line: [540 540 540 543 543 543 543 546 546 546 549 549 549 549 552 552]
 z_line: [84 84 84 87 87 87 87 87 90 90 90 90 90 93 93 93]
```

As you can see, some of these coordinates are identical, due to the lines being defined in different coordinates and then binned to the resolution of the data box.
Now I want to mask all cells in the datacube with a distance larger than 3 cells.
For a single point along the line (x_line[i], y_line[i], z_line[i]) this is relatively easy.I created a meshgrid for the coordinates in the datacube and then create a mask array of zeros and put everything satisfying the condition to 1:

```
data = np.random.rand(600,600,600)
x_box,y_box,z_box = np.meshgrid(n.arange(600),n.arange(600),n.arange(600))
mask = np.zeros(np.shape(data))

for i in range(len(x_line)):
    distance = np.sqrt((x_box-x_line[i])**2 + (y_box-y_line[i])**2 + (z_box-z_line[i])**2)
    mask[distance <= 3] = 1.

extraction = data[mask == 1.]
```

The advantage of this is that the mask array removes the problem of having duplicate extractions. However, both the meshgrid and distance calculations are very slow. So is it possible to do the calculation of the distance directly on the entire line without having to do a for-loop over each line point, so that it directly masks all cells that are within a distance of 3 cells from ANY of the line points?

Comment: `...  there will be some overlap between each of the slices in this for-loop I'd like to prevent`. Which overlap are we talking about?

Comment: For example if the line goes in the direction along the z-axis, the points will be spaced less than the slice of width 6 I used in the example code, so the for-loop will include certain entries along the z-axis multiple times.
One way around this is to figure out the primary axis first and then only slice along the other two axes, but I have to do this a lot of times, so it would be more convenient to have an automated way to slice along the line directly.

Comment: I would suggest adding a minimal sample case and showing us the expected output with explanations on it.

Comment: I added a bit more of a concrete code example

Comment: Are you trying to mask a 6x6x6 cube, or a sphere of radius 3? Your two examples choose different options

Comment: Either option is fine for me, although ideally the sphere/cyllinder is what I really needed. Whichever is faster

Comment: You might want to look at [`scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_dilation`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_dilation.html) to expand a boolean mask where `mask[x,y,z] = True`, `False` elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
# .shape = (N,)
x, y, z = ...

# offsets in [-3, 3), .shape = (6, 6, 6)
xo, yo, zo = np.indices((6, 6, 6)) - 3

# box indices, .shape = (6, 6, 6, N)
xb, yb, zb = x + xo[...,np.newaxis], y + yo[...,np.newaxis], z + zo[...,np.newaxis]

# .shape = (6, 6, 6, N)
extractions = data[xb, yb, zb]
```

This extracts a series of 6x6x6 cubes, each "centered" on the coordinates in `x`, `y`, and `z`

This will produce duplicate coordinates, and fail on cases near the borders

If you keep your `xyz` in one array, this gets a little less verbose, and you can remove the duplicates:

```
# .shape = (N,3)
xyz = ...

# offsets in [-3, 3), .shape = (6, 6, 6, 3)
xyz_offset = np.moveaxis(np.indices((6, 6, 6)) - 3, 0, -1)

# box indices, .shape = (6, 6, 6, N, 3)
xyz_box = xyz + xyz_offset[...,np.newaxis,:]

if remove_duplicates:
    # shape (M, 3)
    xyz_box = xyz_box.reshape(-1, 3)
    xyz_box = np.unique(xyz_box, axis=0)

xb, yb, zb = xyz_box
extractions = data[xb, yb, zb]
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I couldn't fully test your method due to my numpy version not yet having added the axis argument to np.unique. Unfortunately I cannot upgrade to a numpy newer than version 1.11.3 on the machine I need to run this code on.
I added some more information to my original question to hopefully make a bit more clear what I meant

Comment: @Mizuti: Can you deal with having duplicates then?

Comment: I need to determine properties like the mean in all the masked cells, so having duplicates is a real issue